# Can I display all users using php and sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to display all users in the database when clicking Display Users which then will fetch the data in the table `member` and display it below?

I tried the following.

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT username FROM member");


echo '<table>';
while($rowtwo = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
  echo '
         .$rowtwo['username'].'
        ';
}
```

But it's not working any ideas? Cheers

Comment: Try `echo $rowtwo['username'];` and don't forget to close your table tag, or just delete it altogether.

Comment: There are lots of things wrong with this. Makes me question how much effort was put into this before posting. Did you read [the manual](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)?

Comment: `$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT username FROM member");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli query` need connection parameter at first. More about [`mysqli query`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp). Try this

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection_var, "SELECT username FROM member");

echo '<table>';
while($rowtwo = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
   echo '<tr><td>'.$rowtwo["username"].'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the database connection to mysqli_query. That is mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT username from member");

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query(your db connection,"SELECT username FROM member");


echo "<table>";
while($rowtwo = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
  echo "<tr><td>".$rowtwo['username']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```